# How make other applications to download cloud files from my app through iCloud Documents?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Upon tapping on Upload button in Drop box application. UIDocumentMenuViewController shows a list of application which are capable of cloud service. I want my app also listed(If installed) in this. How to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using ‘Import Utis’ where you can import and export the document. Once you have implemented import utis functionality your app will be visible. One more thing you need to implement some delegate on your appdelete file. For more information you can follow below link.

https://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios

Comment: I tried to  present UIDocumentMenuViewController with the changes you have recommended but my application is not still showing